# Tomcat executes JSP files for only one user

Tags: jsp, tomcat, configuration, public-html

I am working on a server with Apache and Tomcat, which were configured by other person (otherguy).
When I put a JSP file (hello.jsp) under the public_html/ folder of 'otherguy', and then I try to access it from the browser like

```
myserver.com:8080/~otherguy/hello.jsp
```

It shows a simple HTML message (which is what I want).
However, if I copy the same file (hello.jsp) to my public_html/ folder (mine), and then I try to access it from the browser like

```
myserver.com:8080/~mine/hello.jsp
```

I get the following message:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /~mine/hello.jsp
type Status report
message /~mine/hello.jsp
description The requested resource (/~mine/hello.jsp) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
```

I looked at the content of the file server.xml, where this is included:

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.UserConfig"
        directoryName="public_html"
        userClass="org.apache.catalina.startup.PasswdUserDatabase"/>

    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.UserConfig" 
        directoryName="public_html" homeBase="/home" 
        userClass="org.apache.catalina.startup.HomesUserDatabase"/>
  </Host>
```

According to what I have read on Internet, that configuration is appropriate to allow any user with a public_html folder to execute JSP files.
However, it is not working for me.
Could you tell me how can I reconfigure this setting so that any user can execute JSP files in their corresponding public_html folder?

Thanks in advance.

Note: The TOMCAT version is 6.0.35

Note: If I put a HTML file (helloworld.html) under my public_html/ folder, I can see it from myserver.com/~mine/helloworld.html without a problem.

Comment: what version of tomcat are you using?

Comment: i replaced the fragment of code you provided in my server.xml file but it is still working as before. So there must be something else modified

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the tomcat-user (the user which is running the tomcat-instance) has no access to your folder but the folder of your mate.

I suggest you to check the directory and file-access-rights - ensure that the tomcat-user has at least read-rights (and write if your application is supposed to write to the directories, too).